# Accessing multiple Methods using ( . dot) C#

Tags: c#, api, methods

I am working on a specific API provided by a client(they didn't created it), and the API have one strange thing that i can't understand it has some class let's call it class **Command**, this class contains a method called **Add**

so i use it like this Command.Add(some paramters here) ;
however the part that i can't undestant is there are some extension methods that could be accessed after Add() in the following manner :

```
Command.Add(.....).GetSomeThingMethod().ProvideSomeStuff().etc().etc().etc() ;
```

i can't figure out how did they make it this way and what it's called.I searched the internet but no luck maybe i wan't searching the correct term .

regards.

Comment: `Add` method returns `this` (or anything else that implements `GetSomeThingMethod` method)

Comment: FYI (in case you want to read more about it), this design pattern is called "fluent interface" or sometimes "fluent API".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type that `Add()` returns must have extension methods defined for it, like this:

```
class Foo {}

class Command
{
    public Foo Add() { return new Foo(); }
}

static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static int Bar(this Foo foo) { return 1; }
}
```

(Or the method `Bar` is just a normal part of class `Foo`)